# How to integrate React with Django api

Tags: reactjs, django

I started a React project with `npm run vite@latest` for frontend and a django project for the backend. I created a simple notes app that works with each other. But they have different ports. How to integrate React with Django so when I go to localhost:8000 ReactJS shows up?

Comment: I guess, it should not matter what backend is, till you can create a backend that exposes REST endpoints and then on frontend you can consume that REST endpoint, using JS-Fetch or Axios?  Not Sure, what exactly you need help with?

Comment: Usually you want to access the react app on the port you expose from vite. Then add a proxy in your vite conf to forward certain paths to your backend.

Comment: @super Shouldn't django provide react to user? I think I need to change STATICFILES_DIRS and TEMPLATES settings but don't know how.

Comment: You can serve the bundled react app any way you want in production. If that's what you're wondering you need to supply details about your setup. I assumed you were talking about in development.

Answer (score -1):

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [newTodo, setNewTodo] = useState({
    subject: "",
    details: ""
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          "https://todo-app-seir.herokuapp.com/todos/"
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setTodos(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://todo-app-seir.herokuapp.com/todos/",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(newTodo)
        }
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      setTodos([...todos, data]);
      setNewTodo({
        subject: "",
        details: ""
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const handleDelete = async (e, id, idx) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://todo-app-seir.herokuapp.com/todos/${id}/`,
        {
          method: "DELETE",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        }
      );
      const data = response.json();
      const copyTodos = [...todos];
      copyTodos.splice(idx, 1);
      setTodos(copyTodos);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setNewTodo({ ...newTodo, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {todos.map((todo, idx) => (
        <h1 key={todo.id}>
          <span>{todo.subject}</span> <span>{todo.details}</span>
          <button
            onClick={(e) => {
              handleDelete(e, todo.id, idx);
            }}
          >
            DELETE ME
          </button>
        </h1>
      ))}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Subject:{" "}
          <input
            type="text"
            name="subject"
            value={newTodo.subject}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Details:{" "}
          <input
            type="text"
            name="details"
            value={newTodo.details}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).